# copying assets between docker containers

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that builds a `/child1` and `/child2` in `/assets` directory. I need to use the assets in `/assets` to another docker container so that 
whatever in container 1's `assets/child1/` go to container 2's `child1/` and,
whatever in container 1's `assets/child2/` go to `assets/child2` go to container 2's `child2/`

I was able to download the first `/assets` directory by doing `docker cp` as a tar.gz, and `ADD` it to container 2 build. The problem is, just like a regular unzip, container 2 would have  a directory `/assets` containing all the assets, while not copying assets in subdirectories to their respective places. What's a correct way of doing this?